# Ignore response from a PUT call - javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, httpurlconnection, httpresponse

I've a JS (Angular) client that makes a PUT request (REST API) to server and server sends back a large payload that I'm not using in the client currently.

Is there a way to just fire the request and ignore any response that comes back? The main need here is to avoid the data cost incurred by receiving that payload. I've looked at closing the connection once the request is fired, but am not sure if that's the best way to handle this.

Comment: shouldn't you be changing the the rest backend so that it sends only status code or minimal data on successful request execution

Comment: yes, that's the ideal option, but that's not possible currently. We need an intermediate option till we get he server update (~ 6mos)

Comment: then go ahead with the large payload method,now just by ignoring whatever response data thats coming in.After ~6mos if the server is updated,vola,nothing changes in frontend :)

Comment: even if I ignore the response in code, the data is still transferred over the wire and is billed. The only way I see now is closing connection but I'm trying to bounce that idea off this community to see if there are any alternatives

Comment: yes,but its a very bad practice to close the connection because you wont know whether the request was succesful.You would be better off waiting for large payload than error prone code..

Answer (score 0):

If able, I think the only way to change this would be to change the api endpoint to not include a payload from the put request.

I'm assuming you are using angular's http class and using Observables. But even if you aren't, your angular client is going to need to read the response status sent back from the server to determine whether or not the put request was successful or not. In order to read the status, you'll need to response, and unfortunately the full response sent from the server.

You could close the connection right after the request, but as I've mentioned you'll have no way of knowing whether or not the request was successful.

Comment: yes, I'm using angular's http class and knowing if the request was successful is not necessary. Is there any recommended delay needed before closing the connection?

Comment: Haven't ever needed to do this myself so I'm not sure what the delay should be. Though I would assume you can do so immediately as part of the callback of the request and the put request will fire then close right after?

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the request just don't do anything if the request is successful.

If you don't want the request to exist at all then do it on the backend.